# php or html or java or something to destory folders after 1h

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, session, cookies

I have a question for you..

I have a website and when a player connect to my website will be generated a folder with website because for every player is unique / personal or something like that.. nvm and i want but idk if exist.. after a player join the website and automatic make a folder for him.. that folder to have a script or something like this to delete the folder after 1hour for example.

short version: is generate a new folder and after idk 1 hour the folder to be delete. i read something but idk what to try.. im newbie on everything..

PS: i have the script with generate the folder. i just need the script with detroy / delete the folder after 1hour for exmaple after is generated.

Comment: This Q&A on superuser may be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/430914/how-to-delete-directories-older-than-one-hour-cron-job

Comment: what can i do with this sir? i can use this command on putty ? you mean?

Comment: the linked answer contains a unix command, which can be used by php exec, shell_exec or other functions that can call stuff outside of php. However, I don't understand why you chose those tags. Also, please provide code for what you've tried so far to achieve your goal. If you were able to create the folders, you should have *some* grasp of filesystem functions, so *some* code is to be expected.